# Create index clustered X NonClustered with include

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, index-tuning

I have a table like :

```
create table x (a varchar(20),
b varchar(30),
c varchar(30),
primary key clustered(a asc))
```

so I'm wondering if I create an index like:

```
Create nonclustered index test on x(a) include (b,c)
```

that index will make my querys that use columns a,b,c  faster?

Answer (score 9):

In this case, the non-clustered index is essentially a duplicate of the primary key*. It will take up extra space and make inserts/updates/deletes slower, but it will not add any benefit.

The reason is that any query that can be answered by seeking on column `a` can perform that seek on the primary key and has no need for the non-clustered index.

However, if your actual table has many additional columns beyond `a`, `b`, and `c` (e.g., let's say there are 100 other columns as well), it's possible that the non-clustered index could improve queries that use only `a`, `b`, and `c`. In that case, it would provide a smaller data structure that can be used to access only these three columns. It would depend on your workload whether this is worth the cost of maintaining the index.

<sub>* The primary key is the clustered index here and, as Max Vernon points out, the clustered index *is* the table. So another way of putting it is that your non-clustered index is duplicating the whole table.</sub>